# 'if not' in a list returns the entire list

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two lists of dates, one is complete, say df['Date'] and the other one has missing dates, say df1['Date']. I want the if statement to return the dates that are not listed in df['Date'] from df1['Date']

I have tried to convert it to a timestamp as well, but that did not work.

```
mylist = []
for elem in df['Date']:    
    if elem in df1['Date']:
        pass
    else:
        mylist.append(elem)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"did not work" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to go through if-else conditions. You can do this using:

```
df1[~df1['Date'].isin(df['Date'].tolist())]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can better handle this with `set` difference. Finally convert the result to `list`, if needed.

```
>>> mylist=list(set(df['DATE']) - set(df1['DATE']))
```

Now, mylist will have what you need.